# Cucumber JVM based test suite as a spring boot application

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-spring

We have a spring boot application which has several web services. We want to develop a test suite using cucumber but as a separate spring boot application. Following are the reasons.
1) The tests we want to run as part of the test suite are intended to run after the application has been deployed.
2) We want to use Cucumber cli.main instead of JUnit/TestNG to trigger tests so that we will be able to send cucumber and other arguments to the executable jar.
3) We want to be able to trigger these tests from a Jenkins pipeline so that Jenkins can pass environment specific args to the spring boot based test suite.

All examples from cucumber suggest using tests as part of unit or integration tests. Wondering if a clean implementation of what we are looking for is possible with Cucumber Spring.

Appreciate any insights or web references.
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to use an example with JUnit? You can then remove the JUnit dependency and use the CLI instead. You don't need the Cucumber Spring dependency. You'll only be making rest calls to localhost.

Comment: @M.P.Korstanje thank you for the quick response. I have a working project with Cucumber CLI, I was thinking if I can make it a spring boot application. Can I call Cucumber cli main from Spring boot application without adding Cucumber Spring Context and Cucumber Spring dependency. In my test suite I am performing web services orchestrated tests once the dev module is deployed in various non prod and prod environments. I was thinking generating a spring boot artifact for my test suite could be easier.

Comment: You can call the Cucumber CLI from a spring application. It wouldn't help you anything though because Cucumber doesn't use the spring context unless it is executing a scenario. And when executing a scenario it starts a new spring application using springs TestContextManager framework.

Comment: Thank you for the clarity, that answers my question.